# Not able to add in app purchases for iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am totally new to iOS.

> Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version.
>   Select it from the app’s In-App Purchases section and click Submit.
>   Once your binary has been uploaded and your first In-App Purchase has
>   been submitted for review, additional In-App Purchases can be
>   submitted using the table below.

**Question:**

Do I need to submit my app to the Apple app store before I am able to test my In-App purchases?

[image]

Totally stuck on this question and there is no answer on net.

Comment: *Do I need to submit my app to the Apple app store before I am able to test my In-App purchases?*, no. Create it on iTunes Connect and then test it in your application. The IAP must be submitted with a new app version. When you're done testing, submit the version and include the IAP on iTunes Connect.

Comment: But I am not able to add the products. When I click on + sign to add products the basket is empty.

Comment: Create a new app version on iTunes Connect. Like you're going to submit an update.

Comment: Already created new app and sand box tester user also. Here is the screenshot - http://screencast.com/t/3gCA74eOZt0E .But still bucket is empty . So that's why i asked - Need to submit for review or not ?

Comment: When you click the + nothing happens? Try a different browser. iTunes Connect is known to be broken sometimes.

Comment: Checked on Chrome, Firefox and IE but still no luck with me

Comment: I'd contact Apple then. Sorry.